# update state from another function with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Room = (props) => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

  return (
      <div> <a onClick={() => deleteRoom()}</div>
    )
}

const deleteRoom = () => {
  //How to update setRooms here
}
```

How do I update `setRooms` in `deleteRoom` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Put your `deleteRoom` method inside the `Room` component

```js
const Room = (props) => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);


  const deleteRoom = () => {
    ... use your state..
  }

  return (
      <div> <a onClick={() => deleteRoom()}</div>
    )
}
```

2. Pass your `useState` functions to `deleteRoom` as arguments.

```js
const Room = (props) => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);


  return (
      <div> <a onClick={() => deleteRoom(setRooms, setErrors)}</div>
    )
}

const deleteRoom = (setRooms, setErrors) => {
  you can use setRooms() and setErrors() here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to define the `deleteRoom` function inside the `Room` component.

```
const Room = (props) => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);



  const deleteRoom = () => {
    setRooms(...);
  }

  return (
      <div> <a onClick={() => deleteRoom()}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass setRooms as an argument in deleteRoom and call it there.

For example

```
const Room = (props) => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

  return (
      <div> <a onClick={() => deleteRoom(setRooms)}</div>
    )
}

const deleteRoom = (setRooms) => {
  //How to update setRooms here
  setRooms(...)
}
```